# CVXPY Not Recognizing Obviously Convex Objective

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy

I currently have a cost function that I'm minimizing, `cvxpy.norm(A@x+B@u1+G - y1)+cvxpy.norm(A@(A@x+B@u1+G) + B@u2 + G - y2)`, with `A` a Variable matrix, and everything else a Parameter object (vector or matrix, depending). CVXPY labels the second norm's curvature as being `UNKNOWN` (tested in isolation), but I've ensured that the argument is real (using `is_real`). Is there any way I can force CVXPY to treat this as convex? I always get a DCP error (objective not DCP) when solving.

Thanks!

Comment: `A@A` is quadratic.  Have you tried drawing for the 1x1 case? Is it convex?

Comment: Why not post the whole script?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I see your point - I suppose the real problem I'm trying to solve is that I know I have constraints on my parameters that enforce that the cost function is convex. I'll have to put more thought into the structure...

Comment: To me, this looks like a math question.  You have two successive states of an affine dynamical system.  I would post it at Math SE and focus on the mathematical content, rather than the code. Once you have understood the math, the code should be easy

Comment: No, I haven't quit. I simply have other things that require my immediate attention.